# Call a class method at the end of the class definition without that call occuring at the end

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

As an example I have a class that currently looks something like this (I'm using delayed_job here, but I have had this issue before):

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  def issue!
    # Do something time consuming
  end
  handle_asynchronously :issue!, owner_type: self.to_s, owner_id: ->(i) { i.id }

  def send!
    # Do something time consuming
  end
  handle_asynchronously :send!, owner_type: self.to_s, owner_id: ->(i) { i.id }

end
```

What I would like is a class like this:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  handle_asynchronously :issue!, :send!, owner_type: self.to_s, owner_id: ->(i) { i.id }

  def issue!
    # Do something time consuming
  end

  def send!
    # Do something time consuming
  end

end
```

Hopefully is should be obvious the latter example is superior from readability/dry perspective.

The problem here is that when handle asynchronously is called, send! and issue! are not defined.

Is there a way to defer the `handle_asynchronously` call until after the class has been fully defined?

Comment: Is it out of the question to `Invoice.some_method` that has your call in it?

Comment: How does `handle_asynchronously` use the supplied method name?

Comment: @JustinWood I really want this code to be in the class definition

Comment: @p11y it calls `alias_method_chain` on it

Comment: @PaulOdeon What is your reason for wanting it in the class without explicitly calling it?

Comment: To generalise I want a function that performs an action on a class method (could call it, alias it, whatever) without that method currently being defined.